# storing and retrieving audio files

Tags: android, audio

So I have a study aid app, lets say I have about 200 audio clips. 1 per question, and 1 per answer. I've read that you should store your audio files in the assets folder. But I can't seem to find any good tutorials on how to do this.

There's got to be a way I can store each clip with an identifying number that matches the primary key of the question and answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the audio files in `assets` folder. You can retrieve the files stored using `getAssets()`. Now since you'll be retrieving audio files , then apparently you might also want to play. You can play the audio files like this -

```
AssetFileDescriptor fd = getAssets().openFd("your_file_name_here");
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(fd.getFileDescriptor(), fd.getStartOffset(),fd.getLength());
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Comment: great, like I said there will be about 200 audio files, roughly 5 - 10 secs a piece. Should I be worried about file size? I was wondering if there's any good loss-less compression api's for audio files

Comment: More file means more APK size. You may place the files on the server if you want and stream them directly.

Comment: This is going to be a locale database via sqlite. I've heard it's not good practice to use the database for storing audio